# Difference between `ChartScrollbar` and `ChartScrollbarSettings`?

Tags: amcharts, amstock

In AmCharts documentation,both `ChartScrollbar` and `ChartScrollbarSettings` have same properties and looks like they bring about the same feature for the stock chart.Any significant difference between them?

http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/ChartScrollbar
http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/ChartScrollbarSettings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so it seems like the `ChartScrollbarSettings` do **not** work like the other settings:
In a `StockChart` a **global** scrollbar is added by default. It does not matter if you're using the `ChartScrollbarSettings` for settings properties, or not. It will be created unless you're using:

```
ChartScrollbarSettings: {
    enabled: false
}
```

In the panels you can still add local scrollbars using `ChartScrollbar` (Panel control is `AmSerial`). They work only for the panel they're inside.

Comment: I would agree with you. But using the chartScrollbar also applies the scrollbar properties to all the available CategoryFields.Kindly comment on this.                        http://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/#&togetherjs=axzx7TGOvr

Comment: Could you please prepare the fiddle without session so i can look at your problem?

Comment: This is just a Stock Chart demo. Have you tried how the `Settings` work? I don't get the problem.

Comment: Of course it's a stock chart demo but with scrollbar updates to it.If you observe the JSON string, there is a ChartScrollBar property with no category axis reference.Yet the same scrollbar is applicable for all the available category axes, something similar to what ChartScrollBarSettings is supposed to do.I don't get the difference between the two.

Comment: Ok. I've debugged a bit and now edited the answer according to what's happening. I'm sorry i don't use `StockCharts` so my first answer based on misreading the documentation.